# Mac OS X 10.10 Meld Error

Tags: python, macos, bash, python-2.7

I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 installed on my MacBook, as both are needed sometimes.

Python 2.7 is shipped by Apple itself.
Python 3.4 is installed by Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit installer in the link
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/

Here is how I installed Meld on Mac OS X 10.10:

1. Install apple development command line tools;
2. Install Homebrew;
3. `homebrew install homebrew/x11/meld`
4. When launched meld, it says:

   ```
   **bash: /usr/local/bin/meld: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**
   ```

From my research, some people recommend to modify the first line in `/usr/local/bin/pip`, i.e.,

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
```

This file is missing. However, if I want to be able to use both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 for Meld, what should I do to make it work?

Comment: A temporary fix is to simply run `python /usr/local/bin/meld`, for a permanent fix - can you update your question to add how did you install Python?

Comment: python /usr/local/bin/meld
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/meld", line 73, in <module>
    import meld.conf
ImportError: No module named meld.conf

Comment: Why do you need to run meld with both?  Why doesn't the 2.7 version work for you?  Is a BASH alias sufficient?  If not, how about a wrapper script in your ~/bin?

Answer (score 5):

This should solve the problem: `brew link --overwrite python`

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux. I have no clue about Apple and the special things they do. But judging from the error messages given it seems that

1. bash starts *the meld program*
2. *the meld program* refers to *the python program in **someplace***
3. **someplace** is wrong in *the meld program*, causing the bash error message

Now here is how you debug and solve such problems:

1. open a terminal (black window where you can enter commands)
2. find out where *the python program* is installed by entering `which python` into the terminal window.

   ```
   $ which python
   /usr/bin/python
   ```

   In my case we can see that python is installed in `/usr/bin/python`
3. Find out where *the meld program* is installed. In the original question this is in `/usr/local/bin/meld`, as we can deduce from the error message in   4. But we can try again the *which* command and ask where the system finds a meld: `which meld`:

   ```
   $ which meld
   /usr/bin/meld
   ```

   In my case this is in `/usr/bin/meld`.
4. now you open the file that `which meld` reported in step 3. and make a backup copy of it
5. now you open the file that `which meld` reported in step 3. in your editor of choice and change the first line, such that it starts with `#!` followed by the path of *the python program* from step 2. in my case the first line of meld is: `#!/usr/bin/python`. Save the changes to the file and retry starting meld. You probably need some admin access rights to be able to save the file.

   1. first start it in the terminal by entering `meld`, so it is easiert to read the error messages.
   2. if meld started in the terminal, start meld your usual way from the gui, and hope that it works, too

The original question mentioned several versions of python. I have also several versions installed, I can ask the system for the different versions:

```
$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
$ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ which python3.4
/usr/bin/python3.4
```

If you have several versions installed: try one at a time when editing the file from step 3.

Comment: `which` is often the wrong command to use.  On OSX, it runs an external program which does not know about your shell functions, aliases, etc.  A better option is `type` which is a shell built-in, and properly standardized by POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended not to use the System Python on osx, but install a separate version of Python (for a list of the reasons see for example this page [here](https://github.com/MacPython/wiki/wiki/Which-Python)).

The reason boils down to the fact that OSX depends on it's own Python installation, which you should not tamper with, leaving unable to update Python or work with some modules.

You can easily install a separate version of Python with homebrew by running:

```
brew install python
```

This should give you a working installation of python 2.7 (`brew install python3` for 3.x) that is located in `/usr/local/bin/python`. This is (if I understand your error messages correctly) also the place Meld is looking for it.

(I like [this](http://nerderati.com/2014/09/03/installing-matplotlib-numpy-scipy-nltk-and-pandas-on-os-x-without-going-crazy/) blogpost for more info on how to setup Python on osx.)